# ansible synchronize with excludes file role

Tags: laravel, deployment, ansible, synchronize

Im creating an ansible role for deploying laravel5 project,
now I do that with a "synchronize" (rsync)

I have my excludes file for the rsync, and the files structured like this:

the: "deploy-laravel5" role:

```
 files
   excludes
 tasks
   main.yml
```

now here is the tasks in main.yml:

```
- name: deploy laravel projects
  synchronize:
    src: "{{item.src}}"
    dest: "{{item.dest}}"
    rsync_opts:
      - "--exclude-from=excludes"
  with_items: "{{projects}}"
```

some playbook:

```
---

- hosts: php
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
  projects:
    - {src: "../../twitter/", dest: "/web/boom/", envFile: "twitter.env"}


  roles:
    - deploy-laravel5
```

now when I run that, ansible says it can't find the "excludes" file

```
 msg: rsync: failed to open exclude file excludes: No such file or directory (2)
```

I tried many different paths but nothing, any ideas how to point to the excludes file?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? If yes, would you mind sharing it with us as an answer?
Did you try to debug it using -vvvv parameter?

Comment: posted what i found and did, hope it will help, and please comment if it is not understandable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I browsed the web and the docs quite extensively, I found that you can't define othe files in the "role" only files for templating or copying.

But you can define the file inside a playbook, so now the file structure is like this:

```
 roles/
    deploy/  (NOT "deploy-laravel5" as before)

 playbooks/
     deploy-laravel5/
        excludes-file
        deploy-playbook.yml
```

and the playbook looks quite the same:

```
---

- hosts: php
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    projects:
      - {src: "../../twitter/",
         dest: "/web/boom/", 
         excludes-file: "path/to/excludes/file",
         envFile: "twitter.env"}


  roles:
    - deploy
```